# is it possible to get the message of each query inside a transaction in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

is there a simple way to print the message (like nb of row updated, nb of row deleted,..) related to each of the SQL queries that are inside a single transaction in postgresql?
Example

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
delete * from X where...
update col_X from Y where...
END TRANSACTION;
```

I want to get the messages

```
n rows deleted from X
m rows updated from Y
```

Yours sincerely
Loïc

Comment: That completely depends on the code that runs each statement of your transaction

Answer (score 0):

GET DIAGNOSTIC <your_variable> = ROW_COUNT, might help. Please let us know with an example, what you want to do.